# cannot apply geometry node for hair curves

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, hair

[image]Hello,
I followed a tutorial to use hair and geometry node for scattering (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U550q0XQNOo&t=603s). So I have my hair curve, the Surface Deform modifier and a 2nd modifier for scattering.

My problem is that I cannot apply apply the 2nd modifier and when I try, I have this error message"Evaluated geometry from modifier does not contain curves". I doesn't change if I apply the Surface Deform modifier before or not

Does anyone have an idea how to apply it please ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround to get the realized geometry which is created by the curves and the *Geometry Nodes* modifier.

1. Add a dummy mesh object (*Plane.001*)
2. Add a new *Geometry Nodes* modifier.
3. Then output the geometry of the *Curves* object as shown in the screenshot. Add a *Realize Instances* node so you can apply the modifier to the dummy mesh object. It's needed because the cubes on the hair curves are *Instances* and instances go "*poof*" as *Gordon Brinkmann* wrote in his answer. The *Realize Instances* node creates the vertices, edges, and faces as you can see in the *Spreadsheet*.
4. Finally, apply the *Geometry Nodes.001* modifier and you will have the meshes of the cubes in the *Plane.001* object.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thank you very much !

Comment: Perfect. Thx much

Comment: You can actually skip all those steps and just add a Realize Instances node at the end of your geometry node on the original plane

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, the *Geometry Nodes* modifier is a **constructive modifier** like some others, too. This means it expects a mesh object as base to what it should apply the created geometry to.

Curves, no matter if hair or Bézier or whatever, cannot contain informations on vertices, edges, faces, they are completely different objects than meshes.

**If** your base object was a mesh, you could apply the modifier - but first of all, since your setup only outputs instances, you would have to realize them first or the mesh would be empty. However, if your GN setup would create instances of curves, even realizing them would result in an empty mesh after applying the modifier, because a mesh object cannot contain curve information.